# Why am I not seeing Cook's distance lines in my Residuals vs Leverage plot?

Tags: r, jupyter

My residuals vs. leverage plot:

[image: residuals vs Leverage plot] shows a legend for Cook's distance lines but doesn't actually show any, though it does highlight three potentially influential points.

I tried very simply `plot(leave_MRM1,5)`, so I was expecting to see them. This is in a Jupyter R Notebook.

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the most likely answer is that all of the Cook's distances are well below 0.5, so the lowest contour line doesn't appear within the plot boundaries; what is `max(cooks.distance(leave_MRM1))` ?
- it is a **very** common misconception that the labeled points in base-R `lm` diagnostic plots have somehow been flagged as potentially influential points; in fact they are simply the three most extreme points (presumably those with the *largest* Cook's distance, even if this is not particularly large) in each plot: from `?plot.lm`:

> id.n [default = 3]: number of points to be labelled in each plot, starting with
> the most extreme.

Comment: The output for `max(cooks.distance(leave_MRM1))` is 0.0619928990927986, so that's well below 0.5. I wasn't aware that it would only annotate the Cook's distance threshold at 0.5!

I'd read that a Cook's distance of > 4/n is a good rule of thumb, which in this case would be > 0.017.

Thanks a lot!